# Rearranging the clauses in my LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Sigh... On my tombstone it will say "Died adding one more clause to a LINQ query"

So I have the following:

```
var validStatuses = new[] { 
  "Assigned", "Donor Called", "Dispatched", "Waiting",
  "Title Rec'd", "Sending Title", "Cancelled", "Waiting"};

var ud = db.Updates
  .Where(c => !c.Sold && validStatuses.Contains(c.Status))
  .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
  .Select(x => x
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp)
     .First())
  .ToList();
```

And I have realized that I need to have the Contains clause after the date.  In other words, I need to select the most recent entry only if that most recent entry Contains "validStatuses".  Right now it will return multiple entries as long as each one contains "validStatuses".

I'd be deeply indebted for assistance... thank you!

Comment: And what problem(s) are you having refactoring the query accordingly?

Comment: _I need to select the most recent entry only if that most recent entry Contains "validStatuses"_ - What do you want to select in case it doesn't contain a Valid Status?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are querying, the results you currently get and what you want to get.  Right not I'm not sure if you want one entry for every vehicle or only one vehicle.

Comment: @juharr Essentially I have 3 grid views.  Each is populated with the most recent entry from the "status" table if the most recent entry contains one of the statuses that grid represents.  For instance statuses A B and C may populate Grid A while statuses D E and F may populate Grid B.  Basically I need to track the status and classify it into one of three grids... each of which would be bound to a linq query that varies in the values of the "validStatuses" array.  Right now I get the same record showing in multiple tables.

I hope this makes sense... running on caffeine at the moment ;)

Comment: @Servy No matter how I've tried to redo the query (likely I'm making a simple syntax error), Intellisense is pitching a fit.

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Then show us what you're doing, and explain, specifiically, what the problem is.  Telling us that you did something, without telling us what you did, and without telling us what went wrong, is useless.

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 - still very unclear. Edit your question and add "this is my data" "this is what to do"...

Comment: If you only want the most recent entry overall, then why are you grouping by vehicle?

Comment: And if it doesn't have a proper status then what?

Comment: @SamIam Maybe this has all mutated too much as the project has morphed .  The end product wants to be to retrieve the most recent record for each vehicle whose status matches a member of that array.

Comment: @GiladGreen then it will be picked up by another query with a different array to populate the next grid

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 - So in that case what you have at the top is what you need.....

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 and it looks like that's what your query does.  The reason it returns multiple values is probably because it returns one for each vehicle.

Comment: OK... I'm sorry if I'm not conveying this well.  I have vehicles whose status is being updated continuously.  I want to retrieve the most recent entry in the status table, as long as that status contains one of the array members.  Each of the three grids is databound to a query with a different array.  What's happening now is that I'm getting the most recent entry which contains a member of the array, rather than retrieving that record only if it is the most recent AND contains a member of the array.  

Is that any better?  Sorry... :(

Comment: @SamIam no... what happens now is that it will return the most recent record whose status matches.  I want it to return the most recent record only if the most recent record matches.  I believe I need the contains clause after it selects the most recent record which is not what I have now, but I can't figure out how to get there... sorry

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 okay, I've noticed that verbage in your question as it was written, but your explanation of what happens with your current code threw me off a bit.  Machine Learning's answer should work.

Comment: @SamIam Unfortunately it doesn't... or it apparently breaks something down the line.  Undoubtedly it's time for me to take a break on this, my brain is mush but my reply to him follows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that this could work (but I missed the latest comments...):

```
var ud = db.Updates
              .Where(c => !c.Sold)
              .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle, x => x, (x,gr) => new { key = x,
                  list = gr.ToList().OrderByDescending(z => z.TimeStamp).First() })
               .Where(x=> validStatuses.Contains(x.list.Status))
              .Select(x => x.list).ToList();
```

It is a grouping by vehicle and it is preserving only the groups where the most recent item has a valid status...

Comment: Thank you VERY much!  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem quite right.  (Please don't hate me... I'm very tired) After the query I'm doing a join on the results and your query seems to break it. If you're inclined to keep trying to help me, the whole thing follows:

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: I see the problem now.  you have a `ToList` where you don't need it.

Comment: After the query, I have the following join:
var unSoldVehicles = (from u in ud  join v in db.Vehicles on                     u.Vehicle equals v.ID  join c in db.Customers on                                 v.Charity equals c.ID  select new {
 status = u.Status, make = v.Make, model = v.Model,Year = v.Year,vin = v.VIN_, charity = c.Name, date = u.TimeStamp,id = u.Vehicle,                  salePrice = v.SalePrice, bid = v.MinimumBid, note = u.Note    }).OrderBy(z => z.charity).ToList();

Sorry, I was trying to get this all to fit into the comments :(

Comment: @ScottKaye I'm sorry you have that impression of me... it is certainly not my intent

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Sorry, have you seen my edit and tried after that?

Comment: @MachineLearning Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I have to rebuild the other queries and grids but I think that works!  I can't begin to tell you how grateful I am.  Frankly this project is getting past my experience, which is simultaneously awesome and terrifying.

I will post again shortly and let you know the outcome but I know it was a lot of work, and I'm sure it was exasperating... thank you for your time and effort from the bottom of my heart.  "I shall return" ;)

Comment: @MachineLearning ... Sorry I wasn't able to reply sooner, other aspects of this project were all coming up at once.  As far as I can see, your solution was flawless.  Thank you so much, you really saved me.  I'm deeply grateful for the time and effort you invested to help a stranger!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer and for your positive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in your question, just move the contains clause after your date.

```
var ud = db.Updates
  .Where(c => !c.Sold)
  .GroupBy(c => c.Vehicle)
  .Select(x => x
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp)
     .First())
  .Where(c => validStatuses.Contains(c.Status));
```

Also, if you plan on using `ud` down the line in a linq-to-entities query, then don't convert your query to a list at the end.